# Storing URLs for dynamic pages

Tags: php, mysql, url

So I have a bunch of dynamic pages generated by entries in a mySQL table. I would like to allow users (and/or admins) to select links that are associated with each entry, but I am wondering the best way to store them, specifically keeping in mind scalability.

Would a blob or a relational database be the best option?

Scalability wise, if each marker had, say, 5 links in a relational database,  that database could get pretty big.

As an amateur, I have never used a blob, so I am wondering for this application if a blob is considerably faster?

I have researched plenty about the specific storing of URL's, but are there any other potential pitfalls you could see with this?

Sincere thanks for any help,
A

Comment: This is not the best way to use `MySQL` in this case, as it's totally not `bigdata` solution. I would personally keep generated sites in files and in database only information where given site is stored.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have heard about this for storing actual files(i.e. photos, audio), but this still holds true for a few hundred characters as well?

Comment: Design architecture with proper archival plan, Means you need to archive mysql table with specific time period.

Comment: @ambe5960 The only reason to keep site content in database would be to be able to search through it a bit easier. But not faster. If you will get about 1000 000 records, your response from `MySQL` would be like 10 (or even more!) times slower than using `find` function on files.

Comment: Very interesting. I guess i have some more reading to do. Thanks. Would up vote you if I had the reputation...